# Erratic Next behavior with ediff-buffers

Tags: ediff

We recently switched from Cinnamon to Gnome, and ever since then I have seen erratic behavior with ediff-buffers, whereby hitting n (Next) no longer reliably jump to the next change. It would sometimes work but sometimes doesn't (the count in the ediff window would be reliable, but the side-by-side comparison highlighting wouldn't jump/change), and sometimes going back and forth would eventually jump to the change that is "missing".

Any advice on how to debug this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this happen if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. But if yes, and if you can find a pattern close to something reproducible, then file a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.